# RegEx result for parsing URLs differs between a 6 character and a 7(+) character domain

Tags: php, regex

I have a pretty simple function to get the domain of a URL. What I am looking for from the returned string is just the domain name (not `www.example.com`, but `example.com`).

Criteria for the domain:

- `some.site.com` should output `site.com`.
- `a.nother.site.com` should also output `site.com`.

I am testing the function and it seems to be fine except for domains that are under 7 characters long.

Here are my sample inputs and outputs:

- `http://www.example.com/asdf.html` → `example.com`
- `http://www.1234.com/asdf` → `1234.com`
- `http://www.exampl.com/asdf` → **`www.exampl.com`**

The thing that is throwing me off is that last input/output.  I don't understand why the function is returning the `www.` when a domain is less than 7 characters.

Here is the code:

```
function getDomain($url = STR_EMP) {
    preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,10}$/", parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST), $_domain_tld);
    return $_domain_tld[0];
}

$url1 = "http://www.example.com/asdf.html"; // example.com
$url2 = "http://www.1234.com/asdf"; //1234.com
$url3 = "http://www.exampl.com/asdf"; // www.exampl.com

var_dump(getDomain($url1), getDomain($url2), getDomain($url3));
```

Output:

```
string(11) "example.com"
string(8) "1234.com"
string(14) "www.exampl.com"
```

I'm not a pro with RegEx, but it seems the 6 letter domain fits the `{1,63}` criteria in the expression.  Can someone explain why the 6 character `www.exampl.com` domain is returning the `www.`?

Is there a RegEx I can mess around with to prevent that for shorter URLs?

Comment: First, escape the regex correctly

Comment: What is your criteria for your expected output? If the input is `some.site.com`, do you want just `site.com` or `some.site.com` (should only `www.` be stripped off)? What about `a.longer.one.com`? Do you want `one.com`? `longer.one.com`?

Comment: I would want `site.com` and `one.com`, sorry.

Comment: [Check this function](https://gist.github.com/pocesar/5366899)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex matches short domains like `www.exampl.com` as:

```
www         [a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{1,63}
.           \.
exampl.com  [a-z\.]{2,10}$
```

Longer domains like `www.example.com`, where only last part fits within 10-character limit of `[a-z\.]{2,10}` are matched as:

```
www         NOT MATCHED
.           NOT MATCHED
example     [a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{1,63}
.           \.
com         [a-z\.]{2,10}$
```

These happen because regex tries to match from as early as possible, so whenever possible `www` will be included.

If you want to return last two parts usually, but last 3 for some special cases like co.uk, you can use following. But since this requires listing all second-level domains in regex, it isn't that good solution.

```
'/[\w-]+\.(co\.uk|[a-z]+)$/'
```

Comment: Gotchya! I didn't think about that {2,10} criteria matching the shorter domain... makes sense, thank you. Im going to mark this as the answer because you pointed that out but Im completely revising the getDomain function based on this example https://gist.github.com/pocesar/5366899

Answer (score 2):

Do not over-complicate your life, change `getDomain` to

```
function getDomain($url = STR_EMP) {
    $parse = parse_url($url);
    return str_ireplace('www.', '', $parse['host']);;
}
```

Output is now:

```
string(11) "example.com"
string(8) "1234.com"
string(10) "exampl.com"
```

---

Regarding your regex, it's not only a length issue, it's also a char class issue [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/rH1sJ7/1)

---

Update regarding your edit, you can use this code:

```
function getDomain($url = STR_EMP) {
    preg_match("/[\\w-]{1,63}\\.[a-z]{2,10}$/", parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST), $_domain_tld);
    return $_domain_tld[0];
}


$url1 = "http://www.example.com/asdf.html";
$url2 = "http://www.1234.com/asdf";
$url3 = "http://www.exampl.com/asdf";
$url4 = "http://a.nother.site.com";

var_dump(getDomain($url1), getDomain($url2), getDomain($url3), getDomain($url4));
```

In which I updated the regex to only match the last part of the TLD.

It produces:

```
string(11) "example.com"
string(8) "1234.com"
string(10) "exampl.com"
string(8) "site.com"
```

Comment: I added some more information above... but using this function, `http://asdfasdf.example.com/asdf` gave me an output of `asdfasdf.example.com` where I am just looking for `example.com`

Comment: That seems to be on the right track, but if I input `www.exampl.co.uk` it returns just `co.uk`.  I noticed you removed the `\.` from the `[a-z\.]{2,10}` portion.. which works for most cases @Thomas Ayoub

Comment: @TJB4rn3s how will you deal will `www.to.us` vs `www.example.co.uk` ?

Comment: I would just want `to.us`, and `example.co.uk`

Comment: @TJB4rn3s please read [List of TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains), [list of SLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain) (like `.co.uk`) and for the record [Single-letter second-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-letter_second-level_domain). Are you sure you're ready to develop a really bulletproof solution?